# Antonym of outcast

Tags: antonyms

I need to know the opposite of verb outcast.

This is needed for a software application with groups feature. I can outcast a user from a group. outcasted users will not be able to join the group.

I need an action un-outcast the user so that he/she can join the group.

Comment: To begin with, "outcast" doesn't really fit in this context. Sounds weird, at least to my ear.

Comment: Maybe look at other pairs, like exclude/include, blacklist/whitelist, ban/unban, block/unblock …

Comment: If there was an "opposite" of outcast, it would be "include" or "included"

Answer (score 1):

How about

> unbanish

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unbanished), "unbanished" exists as the opposite of "banished", which means "expelled", "forced to leave". The verb seems to see little use, though. Examples I found: [here](https://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/2181311-Using-banish), [here](https://tbc-twinhead.twinstar.cz/?spell=37834).

It seems that

> unban

is also in use in this context ([Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unban), [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=unban)).

As an alternative:

> reinvite

which would state that the person is welcome to join again.

Comment: Just because there is (or may be) an adjective *unbanished* does not mean there is a verb *unbanish*; you need further evidence.

Comment: TimLymington: fair enough. I edited the answer.

Comment: The sources aren't reliable.  Other than those mentioned, I can't find any other uses of 'unbanish'.

Answer (score 0):

**readmit**

From Collins English Dictionary:

> to allow (someone) to enter or be admitted again

CED claims that this is a British term, but I disagree and it seems [so does The Free Dictionary.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/readmit)

I think this is a better option than *reinvite* because *admit* connotes accepting, and *invite* is more of a call to something.